# Delayed updates on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I am sending messages on Facebook using my mobile (Samsung Galaxy Pop) wi-fi. Other person is using a desktop or laptop. There is a delay in the update of the conversation ... not real time updates happening like any other chat-box happening between computers.

Would there be a delay in the update of the messages?

Why am I getting delay in update of my messages?

Is it related to Android wi-fi?

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13030/how-do-i-enable-push-notifications-for-facebook-for-android/13032

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's just that the app is buggy.  Push messages have never worked right for me either.  The latest version of the Facebook app (released in the last week or two) is better, but not perfect.