# How do I enable push notifications for Facebook for Android?

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-droid-incredible, facebook, push-notifications

I'm currently running the latest stable release of CM7 for the HTC Droid Incredible and Facebook for Android 1.6.4 (released on 20 August). [According to Facebook, push notifications are enabled for devices that support them.](https://www.facebook.com/android/posts/131145080279409) Since I get push notifications from other applications (such as Google+), I know my device supports them.

I've read about various problems with them, but I haven't found any definitive solutions (or a definitive lack of a solution). I would assume the setting for push notifications would be in the application's Settings menu. I have a number of options for various times to pull notifications down, but I don't see an option for push notifications in the app or on the Facebook website.

Is this just a broken application or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Funnily enough, as I just noted [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/late-updates-on-facebook-using-android-mobile-wi-fi/13031#13031) I believe that the app is just buggy and unreliable.  There's no reason for the individual device to determine whether the application can do something like push notifications.  Android's [cloud to device messaging](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) requires 2.2 or higher, and the Facebook post notes that that's what they require as well, so I assume that's what they're using. C2DM works perfectly fine for other apps so the only reasonable explanation is that the Facebook app doesn't work properly.

The app was updated recently and does work better for many users, though, so make sure you have the latest version.

There are no settings related to push messages in the app or in the Accounts and Sync settings.  Regular sync is every 3 hours at most, which seems infrequent to me — my BlackBerry allows updates every half hour.

Comment: I'm going to update the question, but I'm running the latest version of Facebook for Android (1.6.4, from 20 August). The refresh interval option has settings for 30 minutes, 1 hour, 2 hours, 3 hours, and never. It's currently set for 1 hour, but push would be best.

Comment: @Thomas Ah, your refresh interval options must be a CM thing.  Lucky :P

Comment: I find that interesting that the ROM would have an impact on how frequently an application can refresh itself. If it can control that, can the ROM also control if an app can or can't use push notifications?

Comment: @Thomas Turns out I'm an idiot. I'm back at home where I left my phone and the current version does have the refresh interval options you mention, and I have it set to every 30 minutes.  My "Social networking sync interval" in `Settings -> Accounts and sync` still shows 3 hours and shows up under the Facebook account, though, so I don't know what's going on there.  Either way I would still blame the app rather than your ROM.

Comment: Well, since everything that I've ever been able to find confirms this, I think I'll accept this answer in the near future. I'm just going to wait a bit (until tomorrow morning) to see if anyone has anything, but it looks like it's the app's/Facebook's fault. Thanks.